# Why am I getting x509: certificate signed by unknown authority on Azure DevOps docker push to registry

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a certificate signed by GoDaddy and a Docker private registry. This already has been setup properly as I can access the registry from server. I have also setup a build pipeline on Azure DevOps. Currently the pipeline builds but fails to push to the registry. I get the error;

> Get ***/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Please how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the issue was. Azure wasn't accepting the certificate I used. I even noticed that Postman was also not validating the certificate.

I came across this page which helped me to solve it.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains

To resolve this, I had to go back to the compressed certificate I downloaded from GoDaddy, which has a certificate with my domain name and another one with bundle. I had to chain the 2 crt files according as stated on the link;

> $ cat www.example.com.crt bundle.crt > www.example.com.chained.crt

I hope this helps someone.